# PhpStorm (Re)Index NFS mounted Preject from VM

Tags: linux, phpstorm, refresh, mount, nfs

Setup:

- Virtual Machine: VMware Fusion with CentOS 7.4.1708 with NFS Server config:

  "/dev/ServerPath" 10.20.0.104(rw,fsid=0,sync,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1111,anongid=1111)
- Local Latest OSX:
  Mount:

  sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw 10.20.0.136:/dev/LocalPath /Users/USERNAME/dev/ServerPath

Everything is working great except at opening the Project (Directory) in PhpStorm, each ~500ms it (re)indexes and a loading bar shows this operation (Updating Indices). Except of danger of epileptic seizure I am afraid about the HDD writing operations on SSD and therefore I wanted the ask the Community if such Issue can be fixed and how? The Synchronisation Setting was disabled. Maybe has this something with the way the NFS is exported/mounted?

PhpStorm mentions:

> "External file changes sync may be slow: Project files cannot be watched (are they under network mount?)"

Any Tips are appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Yeah ... network share of any kind is not officially supported/recommended way. IDE needs fast access to a source code files at any time ... and any network adds some latency. File system watcher (that detects changes in files) most likely does not work properly in such case. The official approach is to keep project code locally and setup auto-deployment on save (not just FTP and alike -- it can copy from one folder to another as well)

Answer (score 0):

As far I could tell, the problem is not with the NFS Mount or the Infrastructural issue but how PhpStorm renew it's Indexes. One quick but short living fix is to invalidate the Indices and Cache by going to:

> File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

After that, there is no more quick indexing of Directories and till some unknown change, the Filesystem is handled properly by PhpStorm.